# Type '{ author: Author; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Author'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am totally new to TS and react and I ran into a problem. I tried searching many places and can't seem to fix it. The whole error message is:
Type '{ author: Author; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Author'.
Property 'author' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Author'.ts(2322)
and my code is

```
import React from "react"

interface Data{
  author: Author;
  date:string;
  text:string;

}

interface Author{
  avatarUrl: string;
  name: string;

}
const Comment :React.FC<Data> =({author,text,date})=>{

  return (
    <div className="Comment">
      <div className="UserInfo">
        <Avatar author={author} />
       <div className="UserInfo-name">
          {author.name}
    </div>

  </div>
  <div className="Comment-text">
    {text}
  </div>
  <div className="Comment-date">
    {date}
  </div>
</div>


)
}


  
const Avatar:React.FC<Author> = ({
  avatarUrl,
  name
} ) =>{
  return(
      <img className="Avatar"
        src={avatarUrl}
        alt={name}
      />
  
  )
}
const App = () =>{
  const data = {
    date:"2017:11:07",
    text:"Some text is here",
    author:{
      avatarUrl:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554080353-a576cf803bda?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80",
      name:"teleph0nes"
    }

  }
  return(
    <>
    <Comment author={data.author}
    text = {data.text}
    date={data.date}
    

/>
</>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Can you also show your `avatar` component?

Comment: i have include that in code search for "const Avatar:React.FC<Author>" you will find it in code :)

Comment: yes so bascailly `Avatar` component is expecting two props, `avatarUrl` and `name`, and you are giving `author` 
You can for example do `<Avatar avatarUrl={author.avatarUrl} name={author.name} />`

Comment: wow that solved it. Cant believe how idiot I am. Thank you so much my friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `Avatar` as this:

```
const Avatar:React.FC<Author> = ({
```

And the `Author` type as this:

```
interface Author{
  avatarUrl: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Which means that `Avatar` will expect two props `avatarUrl` and `name`. But you are passing it a prop named `author`.

If you want `Avatar` to receive an `author` prop, then you have to declare that in the type with something like:

```
const Avatar:React.FC<{ author: Author }> = ({ author }) => {
```

Which does what you expect.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ssl=39&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=60#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wFgAoC4AOxiSk3STgBEUYUBvCuOFAVxgALaAC44AQUEioAbh5wAJuySiAzjCg0A5vPK86ADxjrNOvRQC+FKrXqM0zKcOjd9fAG7sUUAKpQAG3ENLWpdBWoUEFU4EPMrCjQIag04AGFcaNo4UWR0GAA6ADE0gB42DgA+OABeAApOARcoABojGBblOksAShrKtwUiGH4oajg6hV5SxWAPODQAlDU1ADkopBr8DJAsmHxKqd44GbmFpZX16K3fNXoASWpMCAOj45OJLw4oPmloGsafygljgAHpDu53idZvNFss1hsbncoI9ngBaSLRV6QqG8QHNAqYpDWHGlUEwiEKMkUqkw87wq6bbaZJC0NHtbHvTjtEnTclzCHTOlwy6I5m7VkwNFdJCc46cGW8k78jwQ6kCmyUcg9BJahSJZKpT7eKC5YiFEqlTi-ZriZwyOCWao1CbWpoyXq1AZDJAjMaTHHTUDaemi674Y3fMiB45qKBoAHu6AFFBfHz+AJK3EoAIwRNAwkbLPHcH69w68gkpIpeASMBgWoTHpety8aupLooRut44y0T4ABMAAYAIwAdlEI5HoiHY-wLSO7X7AGVcMx2nBgGo4EJ6LKFzik6ae+9UyaM-2hDAYGA1KJQaDQChtEg1AV+CkwBchAUkiBQWAIgwBAaIjgArGBAAsQ4ABxDgAzGB8FoigYFjgAbGgmBwfBABGygAPzAIYATALhNRQLhoEFAOBQjgAZMRwCKDUACy1AAO6GKxABWEjwZgLAAEIwaxAAShgAF4AFoAOpFAAngAmgOQiifBhgwWgADiQgeIo2kAJwwXJYGiRJ5mafRHE1COQ72fRACONRwfObxwES-Z0AESCAUO1CvtG7wkgoSrDKM1ABu8pSCscpQ7HsNoyACnYpkCxYbi6CreAUPJHDKKU5YqRyaqW5BkrFFYheQSCGJAsBKEgjD8Lmkj1kAA)